# Can i use MvvmCross vNext with Xamarin 2.0?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using the MvvmCross framework in our Android and iOS apps, but we where planning on upgrading from the master branch to vNext. I have just upgraded my systems to use Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. Is it possible to use vNext on that setup, when Xamarin 2.0 does not support portable class libraries yet?

Answer (score 3):

According to the latest [HanselMinutes podcast](http://hanselminutes.com/362/ios-and-android-apps-with-xamarin-studio-20-and-miguel-de-icaza) official support for PCLs was integrated into Xamarin 2.0 last week - so it might be worth waiting for another few weeks before fighting too hard against the current setup.

For MvvmCross itself, I know quite a few people running vNext on Xamarin 2.0 and they seem to be getting things working quite well.

I myself am focusing on v3 - and this is now running in Alpha on:

- fully on Xamarin2.0 within Visual Studio for WP, WinRT, WPF and Android
- fully on Xamarin2.0 within Xamarin Studio for iOS
- but isn't currently working from VS to iOS

For more information, I recommend you track and contribute to http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1549/pcls-and-mvvmcross-in-the-new-tools - that will remain more up-to-date than these answers here.